# If artifactory aql response rather than status 200 just failed the pipeline

Tags: gitlab-ci, pipeline, artifactory, jfrog-cli, artifactory-query-lang

I have an aql query for clean up to artifactory artifacts. My query sometimes is getting different from status 200 but response status no matter what pipeline still ends successfully. My question is that if I get different response status instead of response status 200 just broke the pipeline. Pipeline should succeed only like below outputs.

Output sample:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "totals": {
    "success": 18,
    "failure": 0
  }
}
```

My aql query:

```
{
    "files": [{
        "aql": { "items.find" : {
                "$or": [
                    {
                        "$and": [
                            {"repo": "generic-temp"},
                            {"created": {"$before": "25days"} }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "$and": [
                            {"repo": "generic-temp"},
                            {
                                "$and": [
                                    {"name":{"$nmatch":"*-test"}},
                                    {"name":{"$nmatch":"*-sample.*"}},
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
    }}}]}
```

Comment: Which other statuses are you sometimes getting? Is there a response message coming back as well? Were you able to figure out why 200 isn't always returned?

Comment: @EyalBenMoshe If aql query return rather than 200, just broke the pipeline. Only if I get status 200, pipeline should be succeed it. Other than that status I would like to fail pipeline. How can I read the output of aql status part and do this.